# Is there a CSVReader class in Java that accepts multiple quote characters?

Tags: java, csv

I'm looking for a CSV reader class in Java that accepts multiple quote characters. An example would be this:

```
SingleQuoteExample,'Hello, this is Bob'
DoubleQuoteExample,"Hello, this is Bob"
```

I want my CSVReader to parse the above text as having two lines with **two fields** each. The CSVReader that I currently use accepts only one quote character, so it will parse one line as two fields and one line as three fields, depending on which quote character I supply.

Is there a CSVReader class that accepts multiple quote characters, so I can supply both single quote and double quote as valid quote characters?

**Note:** By quote character, I mean a character for which any commas within it will be ignored when parsing the line.

Answer (score 1):

You should try the [Ostermiller Java Utilities](https://ostermiller.org/utils/). There are a number of good classes in there, including a very fine CSV parser. At one point in my career, I was responsible for porting and translating parts of our code base, and really found this library a joy to work with (the CSV parser in particular).

*(Having said that, it has been many years since I've used this library...)*